# jQuery validation in rails not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, jquery-form-validator

I have been working on this issue for a day and tried various solutions but none of them seem to be working.

```
<%= form_tag("/report", method: "post", id: 'report-form') do |f|%>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= radio_button_tag :report_reason, 1 %>
        <%= label_tag :report_reason_l, 'Inappropriate Photo' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= radio_button_tag :report_reason, 2 %>
        <%= label_tag :report_reason_l, 'Seems Like Spam' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= radio_button_tag :report_reason, 3 %>
        <%= label_tag :report_reason_l, 'Underage User' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= radio_button_tag :report_reason, 0 %>
        <%= label_tag :report_reason_l, 'Other' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= text_area_tag 'report_description', nil, placeholder: 'Description...', :autofocus => true, rows: 3, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= submit_tag "Report", class: "btn btn-primary", id:'submit-report' %>
    </div>

<% end %>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#report-form').validate({
        rules: {
            'report_description' : {
                required : true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'report_description' : {
                required : "Please mention the reason for reporting this"
            }
        }
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here the validation is: if the user can't leave the description blank.

jsfiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/528p4mvw/). 
Where am I going wrong with the validation??

Comment: your fiddle doesn't have resources (e.g., jquery, jquery form validator)

Comment: @hoffmanc Have updated it..

Comment: jquery form validation is a separate plugin, yes?

Comment: @hoffmanc No.. It is not a separate plugin..

Comment: I see no validate method in the jquery docs.